# How to deploy the app in windows server/IIS

Tags: r, shiny, web-deployment, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have created a shiny app which runs fine in rstudio/Visual studio R tools and now I want to deploy the web application for production through Visual studio.

Can anyone please suggest me to deploy the app in windows server/IIS.

I am a beginner so It would be great I can have a step by step procedure for deployment.

Thanks